# Showing $\Phi(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)f(t)\,dt$ is twice differentiable and finding $\Phi''(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $\Phi(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)f(t)\,dt$. Justify that $\Phi(x)$ is twice differentiable and calculate $\Phi''(x)$.

I'm having a hard time finding the first derivative of $\Phi(x)$. Here's what I tried so far:

Since $f$ is a continuous function and $x-t$ is a polynomial function, thus continuous, $f(t)(x-t)$ is the product of two continuous functions and is also continuous. Since $x$ and $0$ are differentiable functions, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

$\Phi'(x)= (x-x)f(x)x' - (x-0)f(0)0'=0$

I checked the solution and this is wrong, the solution goes like this:
$\Phi'(x) = (x\int_0^xf(t)dt - \int_0^xtf(t)dt)' = \int_0^xf(t)dt + xf(x) - xf(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$

So I tried to do it their way, expanding $(x-t)f(t) to xf(t) - tf(t)$ and I got this:

$\Phi'(x) = (\int_0^x (x-t)f(t)dt)' = (\int_0^x xf(t) - tf(t)dt)' = (x\int_0^xf(t)dt - \int_0^xtf(t)dt)' = xf(x)x' - xf(0)0' - (xf(x)x' - 0f(0)0') = xf(x) - xf(x) = 0$

$0$ again.

Another thing I didn't understand is why they put the $x$ outside the integral, I thought we were only supposed to do that with constants. As in, why is $\int_0^x xf(t)dt = x\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$

I understand the rest of the exercise, I just can't get this derivative right with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The version I'm using says

Let $f$ be a continuous function and $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ be differentiable functions. If $$F(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \,dt$$ then $F'(x) = f(b(x))b'(x) - f(a(x))a'(x)$

Is this correct? Because if so I don't understand how the derivative of this exercise works.

Comment: They took the $x$ out the front because the integral is done over $t$ and hence the $x$ plays no role in the integration. You could also just apply the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to get the result. If $$\phi = \int_{0}^{x} (x-t) f(t) dt$$ then \begin{align} \phi' &= [x - x] \cdot f(x) \frac{d}{dx} (x) - [x - 0] \cdot f(0) \frac{d}{dx} (0) + \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x-t) f(t) dt \\ &= \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt \end{align}

Comment: @Mattos this is an intro to Calculus class, Leibiniz integral rule isn't covered, neither are partial derivatives. I'm supposed to get there just using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But thanks for the explanation of taking x out of the front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write

$$\Phi(x)=x\int_0^xf(t)\,dt- \int_0^xtf(t)\,dt$$

Using the product rule and the FTC, we get

$$\Phi'(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt + xf(x) - xf(x) = \int_0^xf(t)\,dt$$.

Using FTC again, we have $$\Phi''(x) = f(x),$$ and we're done.

Comment: Thanks! I already understand this part, what I don't understand is why $\Phi'(x)= (x-x)f(x)x' - (x-0)f(0)0'=0$ is wrong. Is it because it is a multivariable function inside the integral and as such I can't apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus directly like that?

Comment: I see now that I didn't add anything in my answer you didn't already know. To answer your question, note that at this point in your study of calculus, you haven't learned a general result for the derivative of something of the form $\int_0^x g(x,t)\,dt.$ So I'm not sure what you are doing with your alternate approach. You are certainly not applying the FTC properly, since that pertains to the derivative of $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt,$ which is a different (and easier) thing altogether.. continued below ...

Comment: This problem intends for you to notice that $x$ is a constant in the integral for each $x,$ hence can be pulled out of the integral. You were having a little trouble with that. But look at a specific $x.$ For example,

$$\Phi(2) = \int_0^2(2-t)f(t)\,dt = 2\int_0^2f(t)\,dt -  \int_0^2 t f(t)\,dt.$$ That's all that is going on here.

Comment: Thanks, I understand everything now, including the error in my alternate approach!

Answer (score 0):

So, this was a silly mistake, but I was really having trouble with it. I'm still not sure I understand exactly what is going on, I'm a bit confused because there are 2 variables (x and t), but we have a multivariable function in $\Phi(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)f(t)\,dt$, so I don't think I can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus directly to it as I did at first, because maybe it only holds true for single variable functions?

In the second approach, the error was in the derivative of $x\int_0^xf(t)dt$. Applying the product rule to both functions with respect to x you get $x'\int_0^xf(t)dt + x(\int_0^xf(t)dt)' = \int_0^xf(t)dt + xf(x)$ and then the result is correct.